# On the equality $p(A) = \int_{x} P(A|X=x)\ dF(x)$ in probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to learn some probability, and I was reading something that I believe boils down to the following.

Let $A$ be some event in a probability space, and let $X$ be a random variable with state space $S$ and distribution function $F$. Let $p=P(A)$, and let $p(x) = P(A|X=x)$ for $x\in S$.

The claim is that

$$p = \int_{x\in S} p(x)\ dF(x).$$

This looks natural, but I've made the following argument, which seems fishy to me.

We have
$$p = P(A) = P(A|X=X) = p(X)=\mathbb{E}[p(X)] = \int_{x\in S} p(x)\ dF(x).$$

The second equality follows, since "$X=X$" is an always-true condition, the third follows by definition of $p(x)$, and the fourth follows since $p(X)$ is deterministic (it's equal to $p$).

Is there anything wrong with this argument? Is there a more natural one?

Comment: you mean $p=P(A)=P(A|X=X)$ I guess?

Comment: @user190080 yeah, I did. Thanks. I like d.k.o.'s argument - but I still wonder if mine works?

Comment: No, yours does not work because the third equality does not "follow from the definition of $p(x)$" (neither the fourth, since $p(X)$ is quite non deterministic).

Comment: @Did I don't understand - if I'm to make sense of $p(X)$, then what would it be? Maybe the notation is fooling me, and $p(X)$ is *not* to be understood as $p(A|X=X)$ (which is equal to $p(A)$), but rather as $p(A|X)$? The naive way of extending $p(\cdot)$ to take random variables as arguments looks like $p(Y) = P(A|X=Y)$.

Comment: If $p(x)=P(A\mid X=x)$ for every $x$ then indeed $p(X)=P(A\mid X)$. Thus, each $p(x)$ is a number and $p(X)$ is a random variable.

Comment: @Did thanks - is this by convention though? If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is the probability space, and I let $h(x) = (X=x)$, then $p(x) = P(A|h(x))$, and $h(x)\in\mathcal{F}$ for all $x\in S$, so as a map, $h\colon S\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ (so $h(x)$ is an event for all $x$). Also, $X$ is a map $X\colon \Omega\rightarrow S$, so I would think that $h(X)\colon \Omega\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$, meaning that $h(X)$ is an event, and it's a different kind of object from $X$.

Comment: I meant $h(X)$ takes values in the events.

Comment: @HowDoIMath There are two concepts at hand here, related but distinct: conditional probability of an event conditioned by an event with positive probability (the result being a number), and conditional probability of an event conditioned by a random variable (the result being a random variable). Recalling the definition of the latter might prove useful: by definition $P(A\mid X)$ is a random variable $Y$ such that (1) $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable and (2) $E(Y\mathbf 1_B)=P(A\cap B)$ for every $B$ in $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: @Did thanks, I believe I see where I went wrong now. In a sense, I have two different $p$-functions. One is $p(x) = P(A|X=x)$, and the other is $\tilde{p}(X)=P(A|X)$. The first function at $X$ is $p(X)$ and is just $P(A)$, and my argument in the OP works until the last equality, where I suddenly intepret $p(X)$ as $\tilde{p}(X)$. If I understand this correctly, it looks like it's a common abuse of notation. By $p(X)$ you mean the rv, such that $\mathbb{E}p(X) = \int_{x\in S}p(x)dF(x)$. I even saw some notes, where the author writes $p(X) = P(A|X=X)=P(A|X)$, which still looks weird to me.

Comment: If really the author wrote $P(A\mid X=X)=P(A\mid X)$, they should be shot on sight.

Comment: @Did The closest thing I can muster is a stapler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More natural one (using the tower property of conditional expectations):

$$
\mathsf{P}(A)=\mathsf{E}[1_A]=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[1_A\mid X]]=\int\mathsf{E}[1_A\mid X=x]\,dF_X(x)=\int p(x)\,dF_X(x).
$$